# Access OpenReport not working with Where condtion

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

This must be a very simple mistake. I just can't see it.
My Where String:

```
strWhere = "tbl_final.[Geschäftspartner] = " & Chr(34) & BP & Chr(34)
```

Which is supposed to go here:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "Contribution", acViewPreview, , strWhere
```

Result is that the report opens... but with all records. I've been playing around with different versions of the SQL string for quite a while even going so far as to introduce parameters to the underlying query (which I know is NOT the solution).

What am I not seeing?

UPDATE:
The underlying query is an SQL statement embedded directly in the reports RecordSource property

UPDATE2:
If I create a completely new Report that contains only the fields `Geschäftspartner` and one metric field then the code works. Thus the error must be caused by something in the report.

UPDATE3: Full Query that is linked to report

```
SELECT tbl_final.Geschäftspartner, tbl_final.Referenzwährung,    tbl_final.Periodenbeginn, tbl_final.Periodenende, tbl_final.Anlagekategorie,   tbl_final.[Produkt / ISIN], tbl_final.ISIN, tbl_final.[Telekurs Valorennummer],   tbl_final.[Asset Domicile], tbl_final.[Valor name], tbl_final.[FIRE: Kontonummer], tbl_final.[Special Fund Category], tbl_final.[FRS: Type of Collateral], tbl_final.[Nominal Currency], tbl_final.[Asset Type], tbl_final.[Anteile per Periodenende], tbl_final.[Marktwert per Periodenende], tbl_final.[Durchschn# Marktwert  in Referenzwährung], tbl_final.[Durchschnittlicher Anteil in %], tbl_final.[AVA_TER in %], tbl_final.[AVA_TER Datum], tbl_final.[VDF_TER in %], tbl_final.[VDF_TER Datum], tbl_final.[TER in %], tbl_final.[TER Datum], tbl_final.[Gewichtete TER in %], tbl_final.[TER in Referenzwährung], tbl_final.Client, tbl_final.CRM, tbl_final.[Received TER-Report for 2014], tbl_final.Language
FROM tbl_final;
```

Comment: You don't give us much to work with. What is `BP`? What is the underlying query SQL? See [mcve]

Comment: I have provided as much info as I could, and which I believe to be relevant... Also, short of uploading the database (which I can't due do to comp. policy.), it is a rather difficult problem to describe in such a way that you could reproduce it... after all, my main problem is that I DON'T get an error message.

Comment: *"The underlying query is an SQL statement embedded directly in the reports RecordSource property"* - you could provide this SQL statement.

Comment: @Andre You were right that I should have given more info... I hesitated because I thought I knew where the problem was. Had I provided both the SQL Statement AND my VBA code you guys might have been able to help with a pair of "eagle eyes". I will post the solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After having gone through the SQL statement and ensured that it works properly on a dummy table, dummy query, and with a dummy report, I ended up going back to my VBA code.

There I discovered the problem:

I had written code that changed labels on the report programmatically before opening it with the Where Condition. I had the following lines of code:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport REPORT_NAME, acDesign
Set rptObject = Reports(REPORT_NAME)

'Various other objects being changed here but edited out for readability
'...
rptObject.OLEUnbound86.Visible = True

DoCmd.Close acForm, REPORT_NAME, acSaveYes
```

In the last line, instead of closing a REPORT, I was closing a FORM. One that doesn't exist. Unfortunately, Access never alerted me to this fact! Thus, the report remained open, and when I tried to pass the Where Condition, it didn't apply it to the report (presumably because the object was still open).

The solution was to simply change that last line to:

```
DoCmd.Close acReport, REPORT_NAME, acSaveYes
```

Comment: @Gustav Thank you for your help in trying to solve this!

Comment: Oh, interesting, that was a very well hidden bug. :) I wasn't aware that `DoCmd.Close ac..., "foobar"` doesn't throw a runtime error if the object isn't open.

Comment: @Andre Thank you to you as well... you were right. I should have posted more code! :- )

Comment: I learnt that the DoCmd.Close acForm  command does not validate the object being closed as existing.....   Hmm.. that's fair enough but a definite got-cha bug.   Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Debug.Print` to view your `strWhere` and you will see.

Or try this modification - for a number:

```
strWhere = "[Geschäftspartner] = " & BP & ""
```

Comment: I've looked at it in the immediate window... it looks fine: `tbl_final.[Geschäftspartner] = "#######"`

Comment: I had to #### the actual number because it is confidential

Comment: Btw... I tried it with your variation and that didn't work. I've tried using " and ' as well as Chr(34)... does nothing to the outcome

Comment: BP is a string, saved as a string in the table, and also saved as a string in the variable... I checked in the immediate window using `?typename(BP)`

Comment: Tried the changed line you supplied, but same results.

Comment: And what does your recordsource return if you manually apply that filter?

Comment: I just went into the SQL query in recordsource, used the BP number provided by VBA, and entered it. Result. A report limited to that number: So it works... i'm baffeled.

Comment: Hmm... could it be that the recordsource is directly in the report? Btw... Thanks for your efforts so far. I appreciate it.

Comment: Tried changing the source to a regular query. Didn't work either!

Comment: Perhaps your code when opening the report moots the filter?

Comment: I have continued to work on this problem and realized that it can't be the code. If I create a completely new Report that contains only the fields `Geschäftspartner` and one metric field then it works. Thus you are right... it must be something in the report!

Comment: OK, a tiny step forward. Then rebuild - if not the full report, then just the "mechanics" - step by step until fail.

Comment: I ended up recreating the report piece by piece and testing the code after adding every single element. I ended up having a functioning report, only to then upon running my full VBA Code, have the same problem reappear.

Comment: Then it doesn't work! I checked out all options and tested all variations. In the end when I found it, I made sure that I had the right error, by doing exactly that!

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas.